# Hyper-Sensitive Unity Game after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a simple platformer game with Unity3d. I made a little platformer game and decided to export it by following a tutorial. After I exported it I was able to play it but something weird happened. Whenever I pressed any keys they were hypersensitive. It was making the player go way too fast. In the game view in Unity it worked fine. Does anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of frame per second rate. In your unity game window `fps` was low that's why player moves slow. But then it was build-ed then `fps` is high. For that 
 
In your all movement code multiply your speed to `Time.deltaTime`.

```
player.move(speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I don't know how you are moving your character, but `*` your speed with `Time.deltaTime` then set it's to movement. It will make speed to movement in an *respect* to time not fps.